# nginxのclient_max_body_sizeをクライアント側に伝えたい

Tags: nginx

nginxでは、`client_max_body_size`の設定でアップロードファイルのサイズ等を制限できますが、nginxがHTTP 413のエラーを返す際、レスポンスヘッダ等にこの設定値自体を含めて、クライアントに伝えたいです。
そういったことはできるのでしょうか？

「nginxにある特別なHTTPリクエスト（特別なリクエストヘッダとか）を投げた時、設定値をレスポンスとして返す」ことができるなら、尚良いです。
実際にアップロードする前に、上限値をユーザに知らせることができますので。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

英語版SOへの投稿で解決しました。

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47897258/how-to-tell-client-value-of-client-max-body-size

値をハードコーディングして返すことはできるけど、設定値をそのまま取得して返すことはできないようです。

```
location ~ \.php$ {
    include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.1-fpm.sock;

    # Modification here
    if ($http_x_get_max_body_size) {
            add_header "Client-Max-Body-Size" "300M";
    }
}
```